# /bin/sh: jar: command not found (inside nexus docker container) Nexus image: 3.34.0

Tags: nexus

When I try to run a command following snippet and getting the error like

> /bin/sh: jar: command not found

```
RUN BASE_JAR=$(find /opt/sonatype/nexus/system/org/sonatype/nexus/nexus-base -name "nexus-base*.jar") && \
   mkdir temp && cd temp && \
   jar -xf $BASE_JAR static/css/nexus-content.css && \
   echo ".nexus-header .product-spec { display:none }" >> static/css/nexus-content.css && \
   jar uf $BASE_JAR static/css/nexus-content.css && \
   cd .. && rm -rf temp
```

Need a help/suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like you don't have that tool installed in your container. It's part of the JDK so if you install one or change to a base container with one installed the command should work. What container are you using?

Comment: I am using the following image: sonatype/nexus3:3.34.0